# make error while building GNU Octave from sources

Tags: makefile, octave, gnu, tex

```
mkdir .build                            && \
cd    .build                            && \
./../configure --prefix=$HOME/my_octave && \ [1]
make -j2                                && \ [2]
make check                              && \
make install
```

While running *make -j2* I get the error as

```
error: print: error opening file 'extended.tex'
error: called from    print>latex_standalone at line 1029 column 5
    __opengl_print__ at line 214 column 5    
print at line 759 column 16    plotimages at line 109 column 7  
GEN      doc/interpreter/gplot.pdfMakefile:27911: recipe for target `'doc/interpreter/extended.pdf' failedmake[2]: *** [doc/interpreter/extended.pdf] Error `1make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....make[2]: Leaving directory `'/home/bhanu/octave/.build'Makefile:26305: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failedmake[1]: *** `[all-recursive] Error 1make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bhanu/octave/.build'Makefile:9916: 


recipe for target 'all' failedmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can someone help me solve the error? I am running it on Ubuntu 18.04 system.

Comment: have you added dependencies first? (e.g. sudo apt build-dep octave). Also which octave are you trying to build? I haven't seen a similar line with 'extended.tex' in my Makefile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create file named 'extended.tex' like this:

```
touch doc/interpreter/extended.tex
```

You have to do this inside the octave/.build/ directory.

Do this for any errors similar to this in the future. It worked for me this way.

Comment: This sounds fishy.  I can believe that the build completed successfully this way, but I would be surprised if it were fully correct.  With regard to the particular file in question, I would guess that resolving the error this way results in incorrectly-built documentation.

Comment: My best guess is that octave does not fully support out-of-source builds such as you are trying to perform.  If an in-source build is successful then that would be the solution I would most trust.  That is, skip the `mkdir` and `cd` commands, and run `./configure` and all the `make` commands directly in the source directory.

Comment: Octave supports out of tree build.

Answer (score 1):

Some times the build process tries to rebuild all the documentation.
I am building from the source `octave-5.2.0.tar.lz` file and
the usual workaround is just

`touch AUTHORS BUGS INSTALL.OCTAVE`

between `configure` and the first `make` in the 
build tree.

At the end of build phase I have only two PDFs

```
./doc/interpreter/octave.pdf
./doc/liboctave/liboctave.pdf
```